# OpenMP error in loop collapse

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

In the following code, I am trying to parallelize a nested loop that prints two dimensional array. I went through tutorials and I found out that I have to used collapse clause:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<omp.h>

int main(){

    //int i = 10;

    int grid[3][3];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            grid[i][j] = i+j;
        }
    }

    int i, j;
#pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            printf("%d\t", grid[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that I got an error that says `C3005: 'collapse' : unexpected token encountered on OpenMP 'parallel for' directive`.

Note: before I used collapse, I only used `#pragma omp parallel for` which gives incorrect results:

```
0       1       2       4
1
1
```

Is collapse the right solution to produce the correct results? If so, why do I get the mentioned error?

Comment: Don't try and parallelize a print statement. Parallelization is inherently not ordered, so there's a very low probability that your print statements will be in the correct order. That being said, which compiler and version are you using? The syntax you used is correct, but your error makes me think that your compiler doesn't know OpenMP 3.0

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll How can I prevent parallelizing the print statement?

Comment: Remove the `#pragma statement` and just print it on one thread.... I'll repeat what I said before: Don't parallelize a print statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you collapse loops, the results are not necessarily ordered the way you want.
for example if i replace

```
printf("%d\t", grid[i][j]);
```

with

```
printf("%d %d\n", i, j);
```

You will see why you will not get an ordered grid printed out. In general I would say that parallel terminal output is a bad idea because racing conditions. What you could parallel is the setup of your grid.

That aside your code gives an error

```
fancyFileName.c:23:9: error: collapsed loops not perfectly nested before ‘printf’
```

this is pretty self explanatory. You do not close the second loop directly after the first loop and hence those two cannot be collapsed into one. Without this line, it compiles fine (gcc 4.8.5).

Besides I am not sure about the c99 standard and omp, but in case to be sure you should make your loop indices private.